# Pass multiple parameters from jscontroller to jshelper

Tags: controller, aura, helper

I'm trying to filter the outcome of my code. Essentially, I have two dropdown menus where I pick values -- user and state. I have no problem working with a single value (user). But can't figure out how to work with two (together at the same time).

Here is my controller.js

```
handleStateChange: function(cmp, event, helper){
    let selectedState = cmp.get("v.state");
    let selectedUser = cmp.get("v.user");
    let filteredOpps = helper.filterOpps(cmp.get("v.originalOpportunities"), selectedUser, selectedState);
    cmp.set("v.filteredOpportunities", filteredOpps);
}
```

Here is my helper.js

```
filterOpps: function(opps, userName, state){
        let updatedArray = [];
        if(userName === 'All Users' || state === 'All States'){
            updatedArray = opps;
        } else {
            for (let opp of opps){
                if(this.userInOpp(opp, userName, state)){
                    updatedArray.push(opp);
                }
            };
        }
        return updatedArray;
    }
```

The problem is that I can't pass the STATE variable into the helper (or any other variable after userName). The userName variable is working. I can see both variables in the console log when I do `cmp.get()` , so they are there. But I can't pass them both to the helper. Is it possible to pass more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible:-

I have an very simple Aura Component, where Component is:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="setMeOnInit" type="String" default="default value" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:-

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var setMeOnInit = component.get("v.setMeOnInit");
        helper.helperMethod(component,'a','b','c','d',setMeOnInit);
    }
})
```

Helper:-

```
({
    helperMethod : function(component,a,b,c,d,setMeOnInit) {
         console.log(a,b,c,d, setMeOnInit);
    }
})
```

This works pretty fine when I look the console log. So there is no such restriction as such.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! Thanks for helping me out. Turns out I had a different issue. In the js helper I was doing `if(opp.opp.State__c === state)` , but it was suppose to be `...opp.opp.STATE__c...` (case sensitive).